# What is the practical difference between Response.Write and <%= %>?

Tags: asp.net, page-lifecycle, response.write

I've run into an issue where a third-party component appears to be interfering with `Response.Write` and causing any content within `Response.Write("")` to render before any of the other html. For example:

```
<html><head><title><% Response.Write("HELLO WORLD") %>
```

will render as

```
HELLO WORLD<html><head>...
```

However, any content rendered using `<%= %>` blocks will work **correctly**. The below code will work perfectly:

```
<html><head><title><%="HELLO WORLD"%>
```

I always assumed that `<%=` was simply shorthand for `Response.Write`. From what I've been able to find on MSDN I now understand that it `<%=` is **eventually** converted to Response.Write, but apparently there are a few steps inbetween.

Does anyone have a guess as to why the two would render differently or point me to some documentation/info that explains how `<%= %>` blocks are handled?

**Update:** The control that was causing the issue was the Telerik AjaxManager control from the 2009 Q1 release. Upgrading to the Q2 control resolved the problem.

Unfortunately I don't have access to the source so I haven't been able to figure out why the control was causing this behavior. The issue has been resolved but I am still very curious as to why it existed in the first place.

Comment: Which 3rd Party Component are you using?

Comment: This problem really doesn't make sense... Never happened to me...

Comment: @voyager, I completely agree; this makes no sense. I would question my sanity but another dev has been able to replicate the behavior on his local machine (same project); @madcolor A lot of Telerik controls (ajax, modal popup, grid);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<%= "foo" %> is turned into Response.Write("foo"); once it is compiled. You can verify this by digging through the ASP.NET Temporary Files folder and using Reflector to decompile the dll's you find.